# Where is Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.dll?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, ms-office

I need DocumentSet class from Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement namespace. I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Office 2010 and Sharepoint Foundation 2010, but I can't find this dll in reference dialog. Did I forgot to install something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Sharepoint 2010.  From the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.aspx):

> Represents a DocumentSet object on a SharePoint Server publishing site.

Standard or Enterprise edition required.

Comment: I have Sharepoint installed, the only thing I'm not sure is if its foundation or standard. Is it avaliable only in standard edition?

Comment: Improve your question, you didn't mention this.  Also tag your question appropriately.

Comment: In addition to what Hans' answer: as DocumentSets aren't available in Foundation, neither is this namespace.

Comment: Hans please update your post, that that assembly is only avaliable in Standard/Enterprise edition and not in Foundation, so I can accept your answer.